# How to run back and front using Script

Tags: linux, shell

I wrote a shell script to run my application front and another script to run the back
Im asking ho can i run both back and front with only one script and they sould run each on a terminal window
when i run the script i want to have a new terminal

For now i just run each script on a different terminal

Comment: no , i want them to run on the same time on diffirent terminal window

Comment: Every time I read "back end" and "terminal" I cringe ... what's the end goal of this?

Comment: easy goal i want a script to npm start front in a terminal and npm start front in other terminal

Comment: When you say terminal - are you referring to e.g. a screen session attached to a tty or are you talking about xterms in a GUI?

Comment: im talking about linux terminal

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean this:

```
xterm -e "npm start front" &
xterm -e "npm start back"  &
```

Comment: there is no other way to run it out of xterm?

Comment: What were you hoping for? And why didn't you put it in your question?

Comment: sorry i will , im using linux as my os i want to use the terminal of ubuntu

Comment: So if you use Ubuntu your default terminal is gnome-terminal and you run it like this `gnome-terminal -- bash -c "npm start front; exec bash" & gnome-terminal -- bash -c "npm start back; exec bash" `